# Managed object context isn't passed from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I wonder why my managedObjectContext is nil (in my TableViewController class) when i pass it like that in app delegate:

```
 // Fetch Main Storyboard
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    // Instantiate Root Navigation Controller
    UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootNavigationController"];

    // Configure View Controller
    TableViewController  *viewController = (TableViewController *)[rootNavigationController topViewController];

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]]) {
        [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
```

And in console i could see "Saved" output, but when i log managedObjectContext in my class its nil..

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = app.managedObjectContext;
```

Did solve problem, but i still want to know why previous solution not work?

Comment: have you tried to make breakpoint where you are setting the nsmanagedobjectcontext ?

Comment: How are you creating the self.managedObjectContext property? Is it strong or weak? Also, you don't need to cast the "app" object with (AppDelegate*).

Comment: Is there subsequent code in the app delegate that presents `viewController`?  If not, then the problem is that you are creating a new instance, and setting the `managedObjectContext` for that instance - but it's not the instance that is being displayed.

Comment: @MejdiLassidi no i dont, i guess NSLog output is enough.

Comment: @AmitWadhawan it created automatically by XCode when you add checkmark for adding Core Data to project.

Comment: @pbasdf there is no other code that use viewController..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that very likely the view controller you are creating in code is actually overwritten with the one sent directly by the storyboard. There is no good reason to create a navigation and view controller from storyboard like this in the app delegate.

So your solution is the correct one and also quite common to have the view controller get its context from a singleton or the app delegate. Keep this pattern and stop worrying about the other problem.

Comment: yes, solution works, but as far as i heard its not the best practice to "abuse" app delegate like a control hub, even if it really easy to do..

Comment: There is some truth to that argument, but Apple also stopped recommending to pass a context to each controller. I am using a singleton to give me the main thread (UI) context and create ad-hoc worker (background) contexts. I have seen this pattern in many good projects, I think I have even seen it in some Apple sample code.

Comment: thank you, then i will follow that solution to pass initial context :)